# Is it possible to hit an Endpoint from a trigger on an Amazon RDS SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, endpoint, sql-server-2017

We need a url to be hit when data is updated in an RDS table, hitting a trigger.

***EXEC sp_OAxx*** will not work due to RDS security restrictions.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=876085

Has anybody had this problem and managed to get around it?

**UPDATE**
So far, I've managed to get an RDS trigger to overwite a file on an S3 bucket, running an S3 trigger which can trigger an API call. It's ugly. Does anyone have another way?

Comment: I was just going to note that someone asked this same question a few days back. I was searching for that question to see if anyone had any breakthroughs/answers. It was your question though. :( Now my whole day is going to be off.

Comment: I'm even questioning if this makes sense to try to make work. Ultimately a trigger should be as light-weight as possible. A more traditional architecture (more RDBMS-ish) would be to have the trigger insert into a job queue table like `id | job | job_queue_createtime | job_queue_execution_time | job_success` where the job would be like `Call my api`. Then a separate outside system can monitor and handle the jobs.

Comment: @JNevill The request was passed down and I am not questioning the reasons. You are right. Due to not being able to make file operations in a transaction I need to make the trigger start a job which updates the file, thus achieving a "signal" from RDS.